# Matplotlib error: "x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (100,) and (1,)"

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am getting this error when i'm trying to plot a function. This is some of my code:

```
def f(x):
    return f1
xspace=np.linspace(-3,3,100)
plt.ylim([-3,3])
plt.plot(xspace,f(xspace))
```

Where f1 is calculated previously

```
line1=x**16-1
line2=x**24-1
f1=sym.cancel(line1/line2)
```

My question is when i do return f1 i get the error above however when i write the function out longhand instead of writing f1 it works which seems weird to me as they are both the same. Do i always have to write the function out when defining it before graphing or can i set it to a variable? It seems very tedious to do this especially when i have to graph the second derivative for the next part of it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you `plt.plot(xspace,f1(xspace))`?

Comment: 'Mul' object is not callable is the error i get

Comment: I guess, that this is sympy and I'm not very familiar with that, but maybe you need [`lambdify`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html)?

Comment: Sorry lambdify for which part? i haven't been taught that so i think there should be a solution only using sympy

Comment: `lambdify` is a part of sympy and from the docs (which I linked) I extract, that this might be the exact function you need. Instead of `def ...` you should be able to write `f = sympy.lambdify(x, f1, "numpy")` and then call `f(xspace)`

Comment: Ok thanks a lot i'll check it out

Comment: Thank you so much man i appreciate it, you've cracked it

Comment: No problem mate :D